# Is there a way to xcopy just changed or new files?

Tags: deployment, windows-xp, xcopy

I am trying to deploy a website from my desktop to my webserver and so right now I am doing this:

```
 xcopy C:\source X:\destination /s
```

My desktop is a Windows XP machine, and I need to copy to a Windows Server 2008 machine, but this copies everything and the whole site is very large and it takes a really long time to finish copying.

Is there a way to specifically just copy new or updated files? I see you can pass in a changed-since date, but I wanted to see if there is a simpler way to compare against the destination file...

Also, I am open to using anything outside of xcopy that can do the job as well...

Comment: You can also try Robocopy.

Comment: [How to use xcopy to only copy files if they are newer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6685140/995714)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

From the [*XCOPY* documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy):

> /d[:mm-dd-yyyy] : Copies source files changed on or after the specified date only. 
>       If you do not include a mm-dd-yyyy value, xcopy copies all Source files that 
>           are newer than existing Destination files. 
>       This command-line option allows you to update files that have changed.

So, with your example, it should read:

```
xcopy C:\source X:\destination /s /d
```

Comment: the "/d" seems like you have to give it a date.  as mentioned in the question,  I don't have a cutoff date in mind.  i just want to copy over new and updated files

Comment: No, the date is optional! Thats why it is in square brackets. Did you actually read that line? It says it does exactly what you want it to do!

Comment: The only thing to be careful about with this answer is that the web server and your workstation are set to the same time! If they aren't both using NTP this could either miss files or copy more files than necessary.

Comment: While the documentation states it precisely, it's easy to overlook the `/d` because it's **not that salient** that the date is optional, then look at the other options and think there's no solution. :-)

Comment: Lower case d was causing me problems.. this syntax worked for me; `xcopy Directory1 directory2 /s /D:12-21-2014`

Comment: If a file doesn't exist in the destination folder, it seems that /D with no date specified WILL copy it, which may not be the desired outcome.

Comment: @tbone You can use /u to get around that, "/u - Copies files from Source that exist on Destination only."

Comment: I just tried this. I have a text file in dir1, to xcopy to dir2. Both a.txt in dir1 and dir2 have the same date/created/modified and same size, the same file. I tried the xcopy .\Docs B:\Docs /s /d, and it's asking overwrote for this text file. I thought it should only copy if newer?

Answer (score 31):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) is a good alternative as well:

> By default Robocopy will only copy a
>   file if the source and destination
>   have different time stamps or
>   different file sizes.

Plus, you can do a lot more - the mirror command is handy for websites where you are deleting files as well.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning robocopy - its always nice to learn some of the new utilities available.

Answer (score 3):

Use the /A option. All the new or modified files will have archive attribute set.

Check the below link for details:

[Xcopy command syntax and examples](https://www.windows-commandline.com/xcopy-command-syntax-examples/)

Comment: Yes, but unless you `xcopy /M`, then the source files will **still** have the archive attribute set after you've copied them, and will be copied the next time as well. Requires write-access to the source files.

Answer (score 1):

There's [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), but I haven't used in on Windows. The way I normally use it on Linux is:

```
rsync -avuz src/ remote:dst/
```

which only sends updates (new and modified files).

Answer (score 1):

I have following task scheduled for ~80k files and ~2k folders:

```
xcopy \\sourceserver\share\ Q:\backuptarget\folder\ /i /d /y /he /C /EXCLUDE:C:\backup\list.txt > C:\backup\backup.log
```

the /C option continues the copy even if "access is denied" to file or folder due to it being open or not having permission under service account you run this scheduled task under.

the ">" overwrites the log each time if you want to append you can use ">>" pipe.

Answer (score -1):

[BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) works wonderfully. It will update automatically whenever you change a file. Peer to peer. Update multiple locations at once if you need to. Easy to use.